# conversion of natural language text into a graphical form

Tags: java, nlp

I am looking to convert software requirements written in natural language into a graphical representation. The graphical representation is yet to be decided. It could be UML, petri nets, matrices etc. I want to use an NLP parser or tokenizer for the first step before converting the tokens or parsed output into the required form. I need advice on which tool to use  - StanfordCoreNLP or Stanford Parser. Secondly, I need advice on how the output of the tool can be mapped into a diagram. 
This research is for analysis of requirements completeness and would help in software development projects.Please help me
-Keshav

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what parser tools to use, but for the output, you could probably use a [Dot language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) implementation like [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) ([Java bindings here](https://github.com/jabbalaci/graphviz-java-api)).

I haven't tried it with Java bindings, but with Python, it was pretty easy, so I'm sure you'll have luck with Java as well.